# How to enable StrongBox (available in 28 and above)?

Tags: android, security, android-emulator

I want to test my Android EC key generation code using strong box.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation:

When generating or importing keys using the KeyStore class, you indicate a preference for storing the key in the StrongBox Keymaster by passing true to the *setIsStrongBoxBacked()* method.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#HardwareSecurityModule